# Update WordPress post with cron job

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, cron

I am trying to delete WordPress post after X Days.
And i am using this code.

```
$daystogo = 30;
$sql =
    "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts}
    SET post_status = 'trash'
    WHERE (post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish')
    AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > %d";
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare( $sql, $daystogo ));
```

But i want to exclude some post on meta key.
Like i don't want to delete that post which have FEATURD POST VALUE IS 1

```
  'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured_post',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '=='
                )
            ),
```

Any way to add this condition in query??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is mysql code for you, you can use MySQL "IN()" function for this:

```
$sql =
    "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts}
    SET post_status = 'trash'
    WHERE (post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish') 
    AND ID not in (select post_id from {$wpdb->postmeta} where 
    meta_key='featured_post' and meta_value='1' )
    AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > %d";
```

Comment: Thanks my friend :)